# Java Arithmetic Exception, how to resolve it?

Tags: java, exception

a few moments ago I started my code in java until I got a problem ... In the console was present / written this:

***Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero.***

*at MyPackage.MyClass.draw (MyClass.java:180)* ...

I went to the class where the error came from, this is the code:

```
if (map [row] [col] == 0) continue;

int rc = map [row] [col];

int r = rc / numTilesAcross;

int c = rc% numTilesAcross;
```

...

*col and row have the value of 0* ... I do not understand where the problem is ... someone would help me?

Thanks so much.

Comment: You need to verify that `numTilesAcross` is never zero. Since that is the only place you are dividing by a variable that you shared, and you didn't show us how `numTilesAcross` is defined there isn't much more help we can offer.

Comment: What is the value of numTilesAcross ?

Comment: @LyjuIEdwinson 0 too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only place where division by zero in your program might occur is:

```
int r = rc / numTilesAcross;
```

that means, that you are trying to divide `rc` by 0 - `numTilesAcross` variable is holding a zero. If you want this to work, you need to make sure that `numTilesAcross` will never be zero when this is executed, e.g., use an if conditional:

```
if numTilesAcross == 0 {
    // do something else
} else {
    int r = rc / numTilesAcross;
}
```

Comment: It seems that it works great !! Thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

The Exception is very clear: You divided by zero.
Since you have only one division in your code

```
int r = rc / numTilesAcross;
```

the Exception will be thrown in this line, if numTilesAcross is exactly 0.

I suggest you find out why it is zero and don't process this case, e.g. by just adding a check before:

```
if(numTilesAcross != 0){
    int r = rc / numTilesAcross;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will keep this part of the code in my mind in case I need it for specific purposes :P

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're obviously dividing by zero. The only place this could occur in the code you provided is in `numTilesAcross`. Add a check to prevent this code from running if this evaluates to `0`.

```
if (map [row] [col] == 0) continue;

int rc = map [row] [col];
int r, c;

if(numTilesAcross != 0) {
    r = rc / numTilesAcross;
    c = rc % numTilesAcross;
} else {
    //do something when numTilesAcross = 0
}
```

Comment: I tried your code, it seems that this works great, I'll keep the code for when I need it, thanks :)